# PHP web software for displaying a collection

Tags: php, self-hosted, collection-manager

I'd like to display a collection of physical items on the web.  I have a web host (Bluehost) that uses PHP/MySQL.  I'd like to display many photographs of my collection, and perhaps tag entries with color, manufacturer, date, etc.  I'd like it to be easy to upload new photos, but there's more information than just photos.  I'd like the front-end to be modern, responsive, and nice-looking.

Before I write my own app, I'd like to know if there's something out there that I can install that can help with the organization and display of the collection, not just show photos. I'd like to categorize items in the collection with attributes like manufacturer, date, cost, model names, etc. I guess I'm looking for something more like a database than a slideshow.

Free is nice, but it doesn't have to be. If the software cost under $100 US, it'd be nice.

I'm looking for presentation by individual item (with a photo), lists by metadata (for instance, all items from a certain manufacturer) or searches (anything with "red" in the title, for instance).  I'd like for lists to have a smaller thumbnail for each match.  I'd like to upload one image and have the thumbnails automatically generated.

One use case is for me to be able to search to see if I already own a particular item.  I want to be able to type in a search (e.g. by model number, manufacturer, or description) and see if I already own something that matches.  Mobile access is important, as I won't necessarily have a full desktop environment while using it this way.

Comment: So a page per item, with photos and metadata. What else? How should the collection be presented (one list/album, multiple lists etc.), how should visitors find items they are interested in (search, filters, just browsing lists etc.), should visitors be able to interact (e.g., with comments), etc.?

Comment: This sounds like it could be easily done with [Dripal](https://www.drupal.org/) In fact, someone [asking for a coin collecting module](https://www.drupal.org/node/302212) for Drupal was told "you don't need a module for that-- core drupal can do that no problem. " by a "Senior Drupal Developer".

Comment: Drupal does seem to do what I want.  Thanks, Mawg.  I don't know how this works, but I think if you propose an answer I can make it a solution.  Is that right?

Comment: @KertisHenderson: You could also post an answer yourself if you found out that (and how) Drupal matches your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com).

This is primarily a document sharing software but has excellent viewing capabilities for images, search features and access control.

Easy to install and maintain. Lot's of plugins available for images.

Answer (score -1):

Try Wordpress + woocommerce for detailed display of items.

Comment: Welcome Sebastian!  Can you expand on your answer to provide more details, including how your recommendation meets the question's requirements?  Also, if you have personal experiences with the software, it would be great to include relevant details about your experiences.